# Deploying Mesos docker container in bridge mode but fixed port and outside of pre-defined range

Tags: docker, port, mesos, marathon

I have a server that I want to bring up with Marathon/Mesos. The server listens to port 443 but I want it to listen on a specific port, e.g. 7443. Naturally, bridge mode would work.

However, this port is outside of the port range configured in the MESOS_RESOURCES of the host. I don't want to use Host mode as it means I need to modify the container. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify specific port on brigde mode outside port range. You could use service discovery like consul / consul-template + nginx for listening on port 7743 then route to your dynamic port